# How to generate an ifelse transformer in a PMML file?

Tags: python-3.x, pmml

From python, I would like to add in a PMML pipeline a transformation (X1, Y) -> X2 such as:

```
if Y < -1:
    X2 = X1
else:
    X2 = X1
```

Is there any python transformer that would do that ?

I thought of using a `RuleSetClassifier`, but it can't take a variable as output (https://github.com/jpmml/sklearn2pmml/issues/162).

Manually, I've added in the PMML file:

```
<DerivedField name="X2" optype="continuous" dataType="double">
    <Apply function = "if">
        <Apply function="lessThan">
            <FieldRef field="Y"/>
            <Constant dataType="double">1</Constant>
        </Apply>
        <Constant dataType="integer">1</Constant>
        <FieldRef field="X1"/>
    </Apply>
</DerivedField>
```

and it seems to work, but I would rather avoid any manual hack.

My environment is:

```
System:
    python: 3.7.1 (default, Dec 14 2018, 19:28:38)  [GCC 7.3.0]
executable: /opt/anaconda3/envs/python_3.7.1_eb/bin/python
   machine: Linux-4.14.114-83.126.amzn1.x86_64-x86_64-with-glibc2.10

BLAS:
    macros: HAVE_CBLAS=None, NO_ATLAS_INFO=-1
  lib_dirs: /usr/lib64/atlas
cblas_libs: cblas

Python deps:
       pip: 19.1.1
setuptools: 41.0.1
   sklearn: 0.21.2
     numpy: 1.16.4
     scipy: 1.3.0
    Cython: None
    pandas: 0.24.2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sklearn2pmml.preprocessing.ExpressionTransformer` for translating [ternary conditional expressions](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/ternary_operators.html#ternary-operators) to PMML.

For example:

```
transformer = ExpressionTransformer("1 if X['Y'] < 1 else X[1]")
```